# RSelenium cannot scroll selection with down key

Tags: r, rselenium

So my objective here is to make the desired selection button pick successfully to "**Weekly**"

[image]

While I am directly using the Chrome browser, when I click the button, I can also input Down key (1x) and enter to get it

But with RSelenium its not giving the same response, here is the snippets I use to test:

```
link <- "https://www.investing.com/commodities/copper-historical-data"
rD <- rsDriver(browser="chrome", verbose=F, chromever = "108.0.5359.22")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(link)
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
    
for(x in 1:21){
   webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "down_arrow"))
}
    
time_frame <- remDr$findElement(using = 'id', value = 'history-timeframe-selector')
time_frame$clickElement()
    
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "down_arrow"))
webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "enter"))
```

How to mitigate this in RSelenium?